# Continuous vertical lines in tabular environment

Tags: tables

I used the following code to create a table:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}} 
  Symbol & Units & Quantity     \\  
\hline \hline
    $A$                 & m$^2$   & Area         \\
    $a$                 & m^{2}/s & Acceleration \\
    $F$                 & N       & Force        \\
    $l$                 & m       & Length       \\
    $u$                 & m/s     & Velocity
\end{tabular}
```

The output of which is:

[image]

As one can see, the vertical lines are not continuous i.e., when the vertical lines meet the horizontal lines there is a gap and again after the second horizontal line the vertical lines become continuous.

I do not want the gap in the vertical lines. I want something as depicted in the following picture:

[image]

Can someone please tell me what changes I should make in my code to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Replace `\hline\hline` with `\hhline{=|=|=}` and add the `hhline` package to your preamble.

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable? Currently, your table will throw an error message upon compiling due to `m^{2}/s` in the second row of the table. Also, the spacing around the rows seems to be different from what you show in your output.

Comment: I would not even use vertical lines at all. And I'd use the the lines from `booktabs`. And use `siunitx` to format units.

Comment: I prefer tables without vertical bars :-)

Comment: @Zarko even if you use colortbl and hhline and have the bars in vivid primary colours?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: When did `u` become the symbol for *velocity*? When I was young, the universally-used symbol was `v`, not `u`...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, to be honest, I'm not very strict regarding use of vertical bars. If it happenm that I use it  and  `colorbl`, than i use `hhline` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the desired continuous vertical line, you can use `\hhline{=|=|=}` from the `hhline` package. In the following example, I have also used the `siunitx` package for the units.

In the following mwe, I have added three versions of the table. In the first one I just added `\hhline` and `siunitx`. Here, the exponent touches the horizontal line. To prevent that, I hav´ve added the second table in which I have additionally used the `cellspace` package for some white space around the cells. Personally, I would however prefer a more compact table without vertical lines and the horizontal lines of the `booktabs` package. An example for that is shown in the third table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\cellspacetoplimit}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}} 
  Symbol & Units & Quantity     \\  
\hhline{=|=|=}
    $A$                 & \si{\m\squared}       & Area         \\
    $a$                 & \si{\m\squared\per\s} & Acceleration \\
    $F$                 & \si{\N}               & Force        \\
    $l$                 & \si{\m}               & Length       \\
    $u$                 & \si{\m\per\s}         & Velocity
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{0{p{3cm}}|0{p{3cm}}|0{p{3cm}}} 
  Symbol & Units & Quantity     \\  
\hhline{=|=|=}
    $A$                 & \si{\m\squared}       & Area         \\
    $a$                 & \si{\m\squared\per\s} & Acceleration \\
    $F$                 & \si{\N}               & Force        \\
    $l$                 & \si{\m}               & Length       \\
    $u$                 & \si{\m\per\s}         & Velocity
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lll} 
\toprule
  Symbol & Units & Quantity     \\  
\midrule
    $A$                 & \si{\m\squared}       & Area         \\
    $a$                 & \si{\m\squared\per\s} & Acceleration \\
    $F$                 & \si{\N}               & Force        \\
    $l$                 & \si{\m}               & Length       \\
    $u$                 & \si{\m\per\s}         & Velocity     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the units touch the hline

Comment: +1 for the `booktabs`-based alternative. :-)

Comment: Incidentally, I would use `v` rather than `u` as the symbol for *velocity*.

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have directly the expected output (however, a design of the table with `booktabs` is probably better).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}[cell-space-top-limit=2pt]
  Symbol & Units & Quantity     \\  
\hline \hline
    $A$                 & m$^2$     & Area         \\
    $a$                 & m$^{2}$/s & Acceleration \\
    $F$                 & N         & Force        \\
    $l$                 & m         & Length       \\
    $u$                 & m/s       & Velocity
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]